# JDBC Connection.isValid() for single threaded permanent connection?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc, connection-pooling

I am writing an application in which one thread will have a permanent connection to a MySQL database using JDBC, and no other thread will ever use this connection.

My idea is something like this:

```
import java.sql.Connection;

public class ConHolder {

    private Connection con;

    public Connection getConnection(int checkTimeout) {
        if(!con.isValid(checkTimeout)) {
            con.close();
            con = createNewConnection();
        }
        return con;
    }

    private Connection createNewConnection() {
        return /* a newly created connection */;
    }

}
```

Is this fine? Or is there a need for an actual connection pool?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is OK, more or less.  The only possible issues are:

- `isValid` wasn't available prior to Java 6, and
- there is still a potential failure mode where the connection goes bad between the application calling `isValid` and trying to use the connection to do something that matters<sup>1</sup>.

---

<sup>1 - Note that you can get the same failure mode with a typical connection pool.  The only real solution is handle the cases where an SQLException is caused by a broken connection by restarting the transaction.</sup>

Comment: @MinecraftShamrock 'Race condition' is the wrong term to use here. It is a timing window problem. You would be better off using a connection pool.

Comment: @EJP Do you mean maintaining several connections using a connection pool is more efficient because isValid() and creation of the new connection would take too long?

Comment: @MinecraftShamrock - I doubt that is what he means

Comment: @EJP or StephenC could you maybe explain what you mean by saying "timing window problem" and give an example for the second point please?

Comment: @MinecraftShamrock - ermm ... the problem should be self evident.  1) Application validates connection.  Validation succeeds. 2) Then ... database restarts 3) Then application tries to use connection which is no longer valid ... BANG!

Comment: Oh, I see. Again I've thought way to complicated. Thank you StephenC and EJP :)